# read register value into variable - e.g. control location of pc

Tags: tcl, openocd

Aim is to check if my controller has halted at the correct position.

I'm using tcl-script.
The commend `reg pc` outputs the value of the register `pc` to the console. So in theory following command should store something in a variable.

```
set x [ reg pc ]
```

But the resulting variable `x`remains empty.

How can I retrieve the value of a register and store it into a variable?

Comment: Is `reg` an external command or an internal `proc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of a tricky thing. `reg pc` does not return anything... Why even should it?^^ would be useful -.-

How ever, this one works with credit to the [mailinglist](https://sourceforge.net/p/openocd/mailman/message/33479844/)!

```
set real_pc  [lindex [ocd_reg pc] 2]

# following executed returns the pc at (here) 0x1FC
ocd_reg pc
# returns: "pc (/32): 0x000001FC "

# Now I can check for my pc in tcl =)!
if { $expected_pc == $real_pc } { \
    echo "reg pc is correct! at $real_pc"
}
```

This looks to me like the string is split in 3 chunks. Taken is chunk 2, count starts by 0. In tcl everything is a string. So this works!

Answer (score -1):

What you need is the `exec` command:

```
set x [exec reg pc]
```

The `exec` command executes the `reg pc` command and returns the output.

Comment: thx for quick reply. I get at this line the following error: `Error: ERROR: Invalid Argument/Option - 'pc'.` ... `reg pc`without sorounding works fine. an Idea?

Comment: `pc` is an invalid option to the the `reg` command. This has nothing to do with TCL.